# Where is the Tomboy panel applet?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-panel, applet, tomboy

I just installed Natty on my laptop and I noted that my Tomboy applet is missing.
I click over panel and choose **Add to panel** to try find it but it isn't there.

Are there some way to restore this applet? I like it so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm making the assumption you are running the Unity Interface - if you are using the classic Gnome interface then the following doesnt apply to you.

In Unity, all the previous Gnome Panel applets will not work - except if they were Application Indicators.  Unity doesnt allow you to "right click" and add to Panel anymore.

If you start Tom-Boy from the Dash (click the top left 'circle of friends' icon and search from Tom) you should hopefully see the new Tom-Boy Application Indicator displayed in the top-left of the screen.

Add Tom-Boy to the "Startup Applications" so that the Application Indicator is started when you next login.

Comment: I was using classic Gnome, thanks anyway. But now I decided use Unity.

Answer (score 4):

Just running Tomboy should load it in the indicator area (it's not an old applet so it doesn't show up in that right click menu anymore):

[image]

Comment: I find a way to launch it directly in indicator menu, minimized: I added **tomboy --icon** in the startup applications.

Comment: As per https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665532, there is no --icon option, just starting as tomboy should work.

Answer (score 2):

Tomboy is not anymore a panel applet (you won't find it in "Add to Panel"), but it will provide an applet in the Indicator area once launched (ALT+F2 "tomboy").

So, if you need the new tomboy applet to be loaded automatically in the Indicator area, you'll need to go to "System/Preferences/Startup Applications" and then "Add", Name: "Tomboy", Command: "tomboy".

This applies to Gnome Desktop AND Unity.

This full solution was already provided in previous answer, but was spread into several answer and comments.